# Removing a package without rpm nor dnf

Tags: fedora, rpm, dnf

For an unknown reason my RPMDB got corrupted and after hours and hours of digging I was able to create and populate a new RPMDB, all packages needed to be reinstalled but I have a problem with teamviewer. It says it's installed and not installed at the same time. e.g.:

```
$ sudo dnf remove teamviewer
Dependencies resolved.
=======================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                Architecture                   Version                               Repository                           Size
=======================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 teamviewer                             x86_64                         15.36.8-0                             @teamviewer                         256 M
Removing unused dependencies:
 minizip-compat                         x86_64                         1.2.13-3.fc38                         @rawhide                             55 k

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================================================================================
Remove  2 Packages

Freed space: 256 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Running transaction check
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    4725 
Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0c1289c0: BAD
Header SHA256 digest: OK
Header SHA1 digest: OK
Error: An rpm exception occurred: package not installed

$ cat packages | grep team
libteam-1.31-7.fc38.x86_64
teamd-1.31-7.fc38.x86_64
NetworkManager-team-1.41.90-1.fc38.1.x86_64
```

I've got a lot of this `error: rpmdbNextIterator` but other installations and updates work, only teamviewer is failing.

My question is how can I remove a package without `rpm` or `dnf`?

Comment: you will need to modify the rpmdb using a library that knows how to, and that library says something's broken about the db. "Doing it without rpm" doesn't really makes sense – you're removing it *from database files used only by RPM*.

Comment: What I meant is "without the rpm or dnf commnad, but I understand your comment

Comment: Have you tried [repairing](https://www.tecmint.com/rebuild-corrupted-rpm-database-in-centos/) the RPM database? I don't know whether the method described in the link is correct but it looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Removing a package outside of of `rpm` or `dnf` could be problematic.  Package management is more than just installing/removing files.  For example, installing and/or removing a package may run _scriptlets_ that create/modify system configuration(s), etc.  For example, `rpm -q --scripts bash` shows scriptlets executed as part of installation and un-installation.

Comment: I'm very aware, but in the case of this particular package I just want to remove it. In any case, something that allows me to reinstall and then remove (to run any post-script) will work.

Comment: I just recovered the `rpmdb` that's how I get this error